# Segmentation fault when deallocating pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr

Tags: c++, malloc, shared-ptr, point-cloud-library

I have a function that reads in a pointcloud successfully and stores it in `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pcd`

I then run

```
//filter the pointcloud to remove some noise while still keeping the cloud dense
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tmp = filter_obj.filterVoxelGrid(pcd, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
```

where `filter_obj` is an object of `stereo_pointcloud_filter`

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr stereo_pointcloud_filter::filterVoxelGrid(
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr inputcloud,
    float voxelX, float voxelY, float voxelZ)
{

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr outputcloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(inputcloud);
    sor.setLeafSize(voxelX, voxelY, voxelZ);
    sor.filter(*outputcloud);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr result(outputcloud);
    return result;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault during de-allocation of `tmp`. I'm almost certain the error is to do with some bad pointers in `filterVoxelGrid()`, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here's the call stack

> libc.so.6!__GI___libc_free(void * mem) (/usr/src/glibc/glibc-2.23/malloc/malloc.c:2951)
>   Eigen::internal::handmade_aligned_free(void * ptr) (/home/shawn/Documents/Projects/catkin_ws/devel/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:98)
>   Eigen::internal::aligned_free(void * ptr) (/home/shawn/Documents/Projects/catkin_ws/devel/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:179)
>   Eigen::aligned_allocator::deallocate(Eigen::aligned_allocator * const this, Eigen::aligned_allocator::pointer p) (/home/shawn/Documents/Projects/catkin_ws/devel/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:755)
>   std::allocator_traits >::deallocate(Eigen::aligned_allocator & __a, std::allocator_traits >::pointer __p, std::allocator_traits >::size_type __n) (/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:386)
>   std::_Vector_base >::_M_deallocate(std::_Vector_base > * const this, std::_Vector_base >::pointer __p, std::size_t __n) (/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:178)
>   std::_Vector_base >::~_Vector_base(std::_Vector_base > * const this) (/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:160)
>   std::vector >::~vector(std::vector > * const this) (/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:425)
>   pcl::PointCloud::~PointCloud(pcl::PointCloud * const this) (/usr/local/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h:240)
>   pcl::PointCloud::~PointCloud(pcl::PointCloud * const this) (/usr/local/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h:240)
>   boost::checked_delete >(pcl::PointCloud * x) (/usr/include/boost/core/checked_delete.hpp:34)
>   boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p >::dispose(boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p > * const this) (/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78)
>   boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release(boost::detail::sp_counted_base * const this) (/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:146)
>   boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count(boost::detail::shared_count * const this) (/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:443)
>   boost::shared_ptr >::~shared_ptr(boost::shared_ptr > * const this) (/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:323)
>   read_PCD_file(std::__cxx11::string pcdFilePath) (/home/shawn/Documents/Projects/catkin_ws/src/file.cpp:402)
>   main(int argc, char ** argv) (/home/shawn/Documents/Projects/catkin_ws/src/file.cpp:567)

Comment: When asking a question about an error you encounter, please *always* include the *verbatim* text of the error message in your question.

Comment: You could have code that clobbers memory after `tmp` is created but before it is destroyed, and it is only during the destruction of `tmp` that the runtime notices the problem.

Comment: If this is linux code, it might be worth running it through valgrind, this could give some insight into how the error occurs.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've added the stack trace. I do not get an error message.

Comment: @Owl I'll try to track down the problem some more using valgrind

Comment: in recent times i pushed a few fixes to pcl fixing memory alignment problems in the filters module. It might be that VoxelGrid header was missing the `PCL_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay somewhere in the PCL libraries. I had a few builds of different versions of PCL on my machine which probably caused some sort of conflict. Wiping everything and starting again cleared this error.

Answer (score 3):

While I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem, I found a workaround. I switched to using `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` intead of `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` and the code works fine.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr stereo_pointcloud_filter::filterVoxelGrid(
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr inputcloud,
    float voxelX, float voxelY, float voxelZ)
{
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2());
    pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(*inputcloud, *cloud);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr outputcloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2());

    // Create the filtering object
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(cloud);
    sor.setLeafSize(voxelX, voxelY, voxelZ);
    sor.filter(*cloud_filtered);

    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(*cloud_filtered, *outputcloud);

    return outputcloud;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what the root cause of this issue.